# adding item to jlist from jlist

Tags: java, windowbuilder

Good day, I'm brand new to window builder (64 bit mac eclipse if it matters). I'm guessing it's been updated a lot recently given the amount of errors in tutorial code.

Basically I have a list of items in a jlist which resides in a panel, and an empty jlist that resides in another panel. I need to make an add button which adds from list_1 to list_2, and a remove button which removes from list_2.

The syntax for the first jlist is

```
final DefaultListModel choices = new DefaultListModel();
//all the addElement

final JList list_1 = new JList(choices);
panel.add(list_1);
list_1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
```

Comment: And what is your question ?

Comment: I need to make an add button which adds from list_1 to list_2, and a remove button which removes from list_2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to make an add button which adds from list_1 to list_2, and a remove button which removes from list_2.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).

The example with `Hire/Fire` buttons show you how to add/remove data from the List model. Combine the concepts from both buttons into one and you have your solution.

Comment: While that seems promising that runs into the same problem I've encountered many times before. Specicially getText() is not valid syntax and it's use is essential to the example.

Comment: @babno, of course getText() is invalid syntax. That method gets data from a text field. Your example is going to get the text from the list. So learn from the basic example of how to get the selected item from the list. Then you get the string value of that Item, delete it from the list and add it to the other list. You will rarely find code that does exactly what you need. Try to understand the basic concept and customize. In you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.